# Tabla temporal en un procedimiento almacenado pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql

Cordial saludo.
Normalmente utilizo SQL SERVER para trabajar con procedimientos almacenadas, pero en la actualidad estoy aprendiendo a hacerlo en pgAdmin 4, con el propósito de hacer varias consultas para formar una tabla.
Comenzando con este labor, lo primero que estoy haciendo es crear un procedimiento almacenado que me genere una tabla temporal utilizando el siguiente código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prueba()
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE ttemp0 AS (
        SELECT * FROM tb_movimientos
        WHERE bolsillo_egreso=''
    )
END
$$;
```

Y me sale este error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prueba()
                      ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 19
```

Agradezco sus aportes

Comment: Solo ponle `CREATE PROCEDURE`

Comment: pgAdmin4 es el cliente, la base de datos se llama Postgresql. Igual que SQL Server no se llama SSMS

Comment: Gracias Isanchezo, ya hice el cambio y siguie apareciendo el error, pero ahora sale: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE" - LINE 1: CREATE PROCEDURE prueba() - SQL state: 42601 - Character: 8

Comment: El usuario con el que te conectas tiene permisos para crear ese procedimiento en esa base de datos? Qué usuario es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunos punto y coma faltantes, aquí corregido:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.prueba()
AS $$
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE ttemp0 AS (SELECT * FROM tb_movimientos WHERE bolsillo_egreso='');
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Pepe, me sigue apareciendo el mismo error a pesar de poner los ;

Comment: Pepe, copie el codigo y lo ejecute pero sigue el error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.prueba()
                          ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 19.

Comment: Tu usuario tiene privilegio de crear objetos? `GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA <esquema> TO <usuario>`; Ejecutado desde un usuario con permisos de otorgamiento.

Comment: continuo con el mismo error a pesar de darle todos los permisos al usuario asi: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "bendita" TO postgres;  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO postgres;  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO postgres; que mas debo hacer para lograr crear PROCEDURE